# C# Indexers must have at least one parameter

Tags: c#

I've inherited some code and I'm getting the above error message when I try to run the code. Below is the code:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Scripting
{
      [CompilerGenerated]
      [Guid("C7C3F5A0-88A3-11D0-ABCB-00A0C90FFFC0")]    
      [TypeIdentifier]    
      [ComImport]    
      public interface IDrive    
      {   
           [DispId(0)]    
           [IndexerName("Path")]    
           string this[] { [DispId(0)] get; } //The error is here//    

           [DispId(10009)]
           int SerialNumber { [DispId(10009)] get; }

           [DispId(10007)]
           string VolumeName { [DispId(10007)] get; [DispId(10007)] set; }

           [SpecialName]
           [MethodImpl(MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
           void _VtblGap1_7();

           [SpecialName]
           [MethodImpl(MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
           void _VtblGap2_1();
      }
}
```

I'm new to C# and would like to know what parameter is missing.

I'm unable to ask the original coder. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you point out the line-number where this error is thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error says, "Indexers must have at least one parameter".

So you would need to add a parameter to the indexer, e.g.

```
string this[int index] { [DispId(0)] get; }
```

If you think about it, when you use the indexer you *have* to supply an integer as a parameter.

e.g.

```
string path = myIDrive[0]; // Use the integer parameter to access the element

var wut = myIDrive[?]; // without any parameter, how would you get the Path data?
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string this[] { [DispId(0)] get; }
```

You are missing the parameter as the error says.

```
string this[object myIndexerParameter] 
{ 
    get 
    { 
         // return some value based on the parameter passed.  
    }
}
```

Then you call it like so: `var something = myIDriveInstance[myIndexValue];`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

This is basically the same thing that makes `List<T>` allow for the index of the item be passed in; hence the name of `indexer`.